# Can stripe hold money on a saved card?

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible using stripe to hold money on a saved card, but days later the time of card insertion?

E.G:

I need to save the card at certain moment (e.g day58) before completing the transaction and receiving the money. I also need to hold the money a week before it is finally sent through to me, in order to verify that it is available and block it to grant that they stay available until transaction, or knowing failure from that week before.

Comment: can you be more specific of what you mean by 'a pair of month' please

Comment: For instance, need to check Money and block It After 53 days and get Money at 60 day

Answer (score 3):

Stripe does support authorization and capture (or placing a hold on a card) which lets you hold funds for up to 7 days. They cover this in this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later

The idea here is that you have 3 separate steps in your flow:

1. You collect card details securely with a `SetupIntent` since you're not accepting a payment immediately. See this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse
2. 7 days before the service being delivered, you create a `PaymentIntent` for the correct amount. You pass `capture_method: 'manual'` to indicate you only want to hold funds for now. You also pass the `customer` and `payment_method` parameters corresponding to the details you collected at step 1 and you confirm the `PaymentIntent`. If there's a decline, you get your customer on session to provide different card details.
3. Before the 7 days are up, you explicitly capture the `PaymentIntent` via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture)

Comment: hello, I tought on that flow, but since hold and taking card are always mentioned separately, I did not know if they can work together. Did you ever tested it in this way? I need to know how much I can rely on this solution and if I have to prepare a B plan

Comment: This is 100% the right flow and it will work totally fine. Stripe has supported this for many years